# What is the benifit using netty4 NIO in the client side comparing to the one thread-per-connection blocking IO?

Tags: multithreading, netty, nio

I see from the server side, the benefit of NIO is the capability to manage multiple network connections with fewer thread comparing to the comparing to one thread per connection blocking IO.

However, if I have a IO client which connects to thousand of servers at the same time, can I just have similar approach to manage these connections IO using fewer threads. I tried the approach in [Netty 4 multiple client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989078/netty-4-multiple-client/12991506#12991506) and found it spawn a "Reader" thread for each channel it created.

So, my questions are:

1) what are the benefits using netty/NIO in the client side?
2) is it possible to manage multiple connections with fewer threads in the client side?

Thanks!

I have uploaded the code samples in github: https://github.com/hippoz/ogop-lseb

The sample server/client class is moc.ogop.ahsp.demo.nio.MultipleConnectionNioMain  and moc.ogop.ahsp.demo.nio.NettyNioServerMain

Comment: None, unless you're planning on having a large number of outbound connections, which isn't usual.

Comment: yes, actually, we are using a persistent connection between each client/server. so each client can possibly connect to about 1000 servers at the same time.

Comment: Well in that case (which doesn't follw from 'persistent connection'), you can conserve threads, at the expense of significantly more complex coding. I would get it working with `java.net` first and then see if you have a scalability problem.

Comment: Even i have a same question in my mind but did not get answer yet ? please share if you got your answer

Answer (score 0):

Having lots of threads creates a context-switch problem in the kernel where lots more memory is being loaded and unloaded from each core as the kernel tries to reschedule the threads across the cores.

The benefit of NIO anywhere is performance.  Thats pretty much the only reason we use it.  Using Blocking IO is MUCH more simple.  Using the worker model and NIO you can limit the number of threads (and potential computational time) the process uses.  So if you have two workers and they go bonkers using 100% cpu time the whole system won't go to a crawl because you have 2-4 more cores available.

Have fun!

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch
- [Why should I use non-blocking or blocking sockets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654286/why-should-i-use-non-blocking-or-blocking-sockets)